# What's the IRP handler that transfers received packets to user process in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, device-driver

As we know the windows kernel is driven by IRP(I/O request packet ),

when we request a webpage(or anything else),a IRP is received by NIC ,what's that IRP exactly?

Comment: It depends.  There are lots of drivers involved in a web page request.  Are you layered on top of afd.sys, tcpip.sys, ndis.sys?  Each of these receives a different set of IRPs.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to understand all nitty-gritty parts of this process.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Windows TCP/IP Stack Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819770.aspx) page for a list of the components which are involved in such a request.

The NDIS driver model does hide the IRP which gets passed around and exposes 'callback' functions for the components to inspect/forward/change the contents of send/receive requests.

Comment: How do you change the contents using NDIS callback?

Comment: E.g. Your [FilterReceiveNetBufferLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549960(v=VS.85).aspx) function gets called and now you can change the contents of the NET_BUFFER or create a new NET_BUFFR and hand this to the next layer.

Comment: is there any tutorial on how to change the contents in `FilterReceiveNetBufferLists`?

Comment: You have to look into the samples in the WDK. I can't really tell you what to do, when you don't have a real goal. Do you want to change the contents of received packets? Do you want to add/remove packets. (Firewall? Miniport? ...) [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549960(v=vs.85).aspx) is a link to the msdn page.

Comment: I want to change the contents of received packets,but can't find a working example on how to change the contents in `FilterReceiveNetBufferLists`...

Answer (score 0):

NIC drive is NDIS framework which does not receive IRPs from protocol driver(Tcpip.sys); instead it exports function pointers for protocol driver to call.

Please refer to MSDN [Initializing a Miniport Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff554911%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [NDIS Driver Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565453%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**On XP/2k3/2000**:
IRPs occurs at higher network layer using TDI framework; namely AFD.SYS sends [TDI IoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565106%28VS.85%29.aspx) to Tcpip.sys. AFD is a TDI client which implements Winsock by sending IRPs to Tcpip.sys.

**On Vista and later**: TDI is deprecated, and if I am guessing right, AFD.SYS uses [WinSock Kernel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff571084%28VS.85%29.aspx) to communicate with Tcpip.sys. No IRPs.

Although TDI is deprecated on Vista, if you install a TDI client or filter, TDX.SYS will be loaded and emulates the TDI framework for you (via WinSock kernel also). In this case, we still see TDI IRPs from TDI-client ---(TDI)---> TDX ---(WSK)---> TCPIP.